# Video Calling application UI

Tags: html, css

We want to develop one of our video calling application UI as below.

[image: Video Calling app UI]

The main person which user clicks will stay on the main div and remaining participants should stay on left and right side.

So, far we have the like occupying all the space that parent has.[Current sample fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j30t5L6g/)

```
 <style type="text/css">
   .code-snippet-demo-parent-div {
      list-style:none; margin:0; padding:0; 
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      width: 100%;
   }
   .code-snippet-demo-parent-div div {
      white-space:nowrap;
      border:1px solid #cccccc;
      padding:5px; 
      flex: auto;
   }
</style>
<div class="code-snippet-demo-parent-div">
   <div>test test</div>
   <div>test</div>
   <div>test testtest</div>
   <div>testtest</div>
   <div>test</div>
   <div>test test test</div>
   <div>test test</div>
   <div>test</div>
   <div>test test</div>
   <div>test</div>
   <div>test test</div>
   <div>test</div>
</div>
```

Any idea on how to implement UI as shown in the Image?

Comment: Hint: use `display: grid`. It'll make your life simple.

Comment: `float` any good?

Comment: @agdhruv, it making each div as row kind of

Comment: I didn't mean to answer your question. Read about `display: grid`. Here's a link that helped me learn it: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/